# I have some textfields inside tableview cell. The text entered inside the cell are not updating

Tags: swift, swift5

I need a help. I have a table view with list of countries. I want to have add new row button which i did and made the next view i.e. of form type.
The textfields are inside another tableview cell.
All things are running fine.
But when i type the datas inside the textfields and finally press save button. The datas are not getting updated on the main tableview.
Blank spaces are coming.
Any help is highly respected.
[Textfields are initialized here.[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ha87a.jpg)

The cells are added with the textfields.

[The saving button action part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZDOl.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to reload the table view after save?

e.g.

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: Yes, please check the image "The saving button action part"